# If $G$ acts such that $|\mbox{fix}(g)|\in \{0,p\}$ for $g \ne 1$ and $N \unlhd G$. Then every element outside of $N$ fixes at most $p$ $N$-orbits.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups, permutations, group-actions

Let $G$ be a transitive permutation group acting on $\Omega$ such that each nontrivial element either fixes no point or exactly $p$ points for some prime $p$. Also assume that for $g \notin N_G(G_{\alpha})$ we have
$$
 G_{\alpha} \cap G_{\alpha}^g = 1
$$
and denote by $\overline \alpha$ the set of $p$ fixed points of $G_{\alpha}$. Suppose further we have a normal subgroup $N \unlhd G$ of order coprime to $p$.
The orbits of $N$ form a system of blocks, and $G$ acts naturally on them.

Then why we have that:

> No element of $G$ outside $N$ fixes more than $p$ orbits of $N$.

I thought part of this statement involves that the kernel of the action is precisely $N$ (in this case for the elements outside of $N$ it would be just left to show that they only fix $p$ orbits of $N$), but as I learned here in the forum, this is neither true [in the general situation](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1565907/the-kernel-of-an-action-on-blocks-specifically-the-action-on-the-orbits-of-norm), nor in a more restricted situation [of the above assumptions](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1567277/the-kernel-of-an-action-on-the-orbits-of-normal-subgroup-if-group-acts-such-that). This is a statement from a published paper, but maybe they forgot to state that $p$ must be odd, as the counterexample in the other post uses $p = 2$; but nevertheless I am not able to prove it or see why it should be true. So I am asking you for help?!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $\Delta$ be an orbit of $N$. We claim that no element of $g$ that fixes $\Delta$ can fix more than one point of $\Delta$. If it did then, by arguments we have seen before, all $p$ of its fixed points would lie in $\Delta$. But that would imply $p$ divide $|\Delta|$, which is not possible because $N$ is a $p'$-group.

Now let $g \in G \setminus N$ and suppsoe that $g$ fixes $\Delta$. Then by multiplying $g$ by an element of $N$, we may assume that $g$ fixes a point $\alpha \in \Delta$. So by the above, $\alpha$ is the unique fixed point of $g$ and all its powers in $\Delta$ and hence all of its orbits on $\Delta$ must have the same length $|g|$, which must divide $|\Delta|-1$. So $g$ fixes a (unique) point in each orbit of $N$ that it fixes, and hence it cannot fix more than $p$ such orbits.

I have the feeling that all of these arguments have been used in answers to previous queries.

Comment: Yes, thank you for your great answers. But still what I do not get, and also in other arguments, is that we are not talking about one $g$, but $gn^{-1}$ for some $n \in N$. You put it aside by simply noting that "multiplying $g$ by an element of $N$"; but if I consider some fixed $g$ then for each different orbit that it stabilizes the element of $N$ might be different, i.e. if $g$ stabilizes two orbits $\Delta, \Delta'$, then we have that $gn$ fixes a point in $\Delta$, and $gn'$ some in $\Delta'$ for some $n,n'$. But maybe $gn \ne gn'$ (or are their fixed point sets equal?)...

Comment: But we have had that discussed exactly that point before. You only need to replace $g$ by $gn^{-1}$ once, for the first orbit of $N$ that it fixes. That tells you that the order of $g$ divides $|\Delta|-1$. That means that ir must fix a point in every other orbit that it fixes, without having to adjust $g$ again.

Comment: Oh yes, now I get it; I somehow confused that! Okay, now everything is clear, thank you. One other point which caused much confusion in my other queries because I did not saw it then: all elements from a point stabilizer have the same set of fixed points. This is also used above in concluding that all powers of $g$ also have no other fixed points in $\Delta$. This is also stated in the assumptions with $\overline \alpha$, but I was ignorant of that which caused me a lot of trouble in following some arguments, but now it is clear! :)

Comment: Maybe may I add: Merely that $|g|$ divides $|\Delta| - 1$ isn't enough that $\Delta^g = \Delta$ implies $g$ has a fixed point on $\Delta$. But what your reasoning shows is that if $g$ fixes a point, it fixes a unique one, and if it fixes no point, then $g$ acts regular on $\Delta$ (as $g$ and all its powers have the same set of fixed points). So all of its orbits have the same length $|g|$, which shows that it must have a fixed point, a contradiction. Hence if $\Delta^g = \Delta$ it fixes a unique point. This might be clear to you, but I just wanted to add it.

Comment: Sorry, there is still something unclear. When you replace $g$ by $gn^{-1}$, the order of $gn^{-1}$ might be different from that of $g$, or? So how could you apply for example the result that $|gn^{-1}|$ divides $|\Delta|-1$ to $g$? I mean if $\Delta^g = \Delta$, your go that $gn^{-1}$ fixes a point in $\Delta$, so $|gn^{-1}|$ divides $|\Delta|-1$, so $gn^{-1}$ could fix at most $p$ orbits; but what does this tell us about $g$? If $g$ fixes another orbit we might get $gn'^{-1}$ for a different $n'$, your reasoning just makes sense if $|g| = |gn^{-1}|$, but I am not sure about that?

Comment: If the result we are trying to prove is true for $gn^{-1}$ then it is true for $g$.

Comment: Ok, you mean that if $gn^{-1}$ fixes $p$ orbits, then $g$ fixes $p$ orbits and vice versa as $\Delta^{gn^{-1}} = \Delta$ iff $\Delta^g = \Delta$? Okay, then it is clear; but one question, that does not necessarily mean that $g$ has a fixed point itself in $\Delta$, right?

Answer (score 0):

Just as a note and addition. I guess I have an alternative proof. By googling I found [the result](https://books.google.de/books?id=K_DrCAAAQBAJ&pg=PA147&lpg=PA147&dq=profinite%20frobenius%20groups&source=bl&ots=_l2gOZeq8R&sig=NwRkMsDKwHIPfWUVUXXY-goqINQ&hl=en&sa=X&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=profinite%20frobenius%20groups&f=false) that for a Frobenius group each normal subgroup either contains the kernel, or is striclty contained in the kernel. By this, if $\Delta^g = \Delta$ and seeing that $G_{\alpha}N$ for $\alpha \in N$ is a Frobenius group (we have a point such that every element fixing that point fixes no other point, and some nontrivial element fixes that point), I guess we must have $K \le N$ if $K$ denotes its Frobenius kernel. As $N$ is normal in $G_{\alpha}N$ and if $N_{\alpha} \ne 1$ the case $N \le K$ is not possible, and if $N_{\alpha} = 1$ we would have $|N| = |K|$, hence $N = K$. So that if $\Delta^g = \Delta$ we have $g \in G_{\alpha}N$ and if $g$ fixes no point this would imply $g \in K \le N$, giving that for each element $g$ outside of $N$ we have $\Delta^g = \Delta$ $\Leftrightarrow$ $g$ fixes exactly one point in $\Delta$.

So it seems to hold that for arbitrary $g \notin N$ (and not just the ones of the form $gn^{-1}$ which are contained in some point stabilizer) we have that $\Delta^g = \Delta$, then $g$ fixes a point in $\Delta$, see my last comment under Derek's answer.